# Loop through values and insert multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in Excel:

```
| id  | count     |
|-----|-----------|
| 1   | 3         |
| 2   | 4, 70, 29 |
| 3   | 20, 15    |
| ... | ...       |
| 101 | 16        |
| 102 | 88, 92    |
```

And I would like to import it into my MySQL database like this:

```
| id  | count  |
|-----|--------|
| 1   | 3      |
| 2   | 29     |
| 2   | 70     |
| 2   | 29     |
| 3   | 20     |
| 3   | 15     |
| ... | ...    |
| 101 | 16     |
| 102 | 88     |
| 102 | 92     |
```

Is there a way that I can loop through each value, and perhaps perform something similar to `INSERT (id, count) VALUES (1, 3), (2, 29)...` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row

Comment: Is it regular task or once-only? In the second case I recommend to convert data in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, it would take a messy Stored procedure using some kind of loop, `TRIM()`, `MID()`, and `LOCATE()`.

If you are facile in some other programming language, contemplate using it.

Comment: It's actually not too bad in SQL.  It's much easier in Postgres or something other than MySql because you can use the string_to_array function.  But in MySql there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row